# How to remove a blank page after title from report?

Tags: report

This is my MWE. How can I have the copyright page right after the title page?

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, hidelinks]{report} 

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, includefoot, footskip=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\large}
\addbibresource{references.bib} 
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\doublespacing

% Title page:
\title{\textbf{\Huge{My title}}} 

\author{by\\\vspace{0.5cm}
      \textbf{My Name}\\ 
      }

\date{June 2022}

\maketitle

% Copyright page:

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\hspace{0pt}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\textcopyright~~My Name\\ 
All Rights Reserved, 2022 
\end{center}
\vfill
\hspace{0pt}


\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you really compile this code? Compilation fails to due to two attempts to load `inputenc` with different options. Tip if you're using a recent LaTeX version: `inputenc` is no longer necessary if you're using UTF8.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I have some errors but it does produce a PDF. Works on Overleaf

Comment: "Works" is a bit misleading. Overleaf is a useful tool, but it behaves very badly with errors, by trying to force-compile documents anyway. This can create the illusion that your code is correct while leading to undefined results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `\cleardoublepage` on line 49.

For [the reference](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_103.html), "The `\cleardoublepage` command ends the current page and causes all figures and tables that have so far appeared in the input to be printed."

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, hidelinks]{report} 

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, includefoot, footskip=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\large}
\addbibresource{references.bib} 
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{microtype}      
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\doublespacing

% Title page:
\title{\textbf{\Huge{My title}}} 

\author{by\\\vspace{0.5cm}
      \textbf{My Name}\\ 
      }

\date{June 2022}

\maketitle

% Copyright page:

% HERE: this is the culprit, remove it or comment out
% \cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\hspace{0pt}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\textcopyright~~My Name\\ 
All Rights Reserved, 2022 
\end{center}
\vfill
\hspace{0pt}


\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Thank you! yes you are absolutely right! I thought I used this command to delete the blank page..

Comment: @stargazer45 Thanks you, glad to help :) feel free to mark the answer as correct :)